# How to show a particular URL to the user depending on JSON input using ngIf? (Angular)

Tags: json, angular

In Angular, how to use *ngIf to check whether a JSON value includes a certain string, and then show them a certain URL ? In my case I have a object name called campaigns.description which has a value that includes a description. I want to see whether a given string, for example "one beam" is included in that description and show an URL based on that.

So not the way that the value equals a certain string, but the text that is held within the value includes a certain string.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `indexof()` function to check the existence of some substring inside a string. This function returns '-1' if the substring is not present in the string.

```
<label *ngIf="campaigns.description.indexOf('One Beam') != -1 ? true : false">{{urlToShow}}</label>
```

Comment: `? true : false` is redundant, the result of `!=` is already a boolean. Also, keep in mind that expressions in templates are evaluated very often (usually on each change detection cycle), so if the string is very long, it may cause performance problems.

Comment: Thank you. For further clarification, how does it know where to look for the string? Additionally, why would I want it to return '-1' if the substring is not present?

Comment: @mntblnk that's just the behaviour of indexOf - https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf

Answer (score 1):

You could generally use [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) to check whether a string contains a sub-string.

```js
console.log("Sample string".indexOf('string'));
console.log("Sample string".indexOf('not'));
```

The Angular part:

#### Trivial (not recommended)

Trivial solution is to check directly in the `*ngIf` condition

```html
<div *ngIf="campaigns.description.indexOf('one beam') !== -1; else other">
  <!-- contains the sub-string -->
</div>
<ng-template #other>
  <!-- does not contain the sub-string -->
</ng-template>
```

However binding a function to `*ngIf` directive with default change detection strategy would trigger the function for each change detection cycle. It might lead to performance issues.

#### Additional property (recommended)

You could introduce additional property to hold the result of the condition in the controller and use it in the template.

Controller (*.ts)

```js
// I assume `campaigns` is initialized in a subscription

ngOnInit() {
  someObservable.subscription(
    (res: any) => {
      this.campaigns = {
        ...res,
        subString: res.description.indexOf('one beam') !== -1
      }
    },
    (error: any) => { }
  );
}
```

Template (*.html)

```html
<div *ngIf="campaigns?.subString; else other">
  <!-- contains the sub-string -->
</div>
<ng-template #other>
  <!-- does not contain the sub-string -->
</ng-template>
```